# Cannot install Jenkins 2.x on ubuntu 14.04 other than the latest

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, apt

I am trying to install jenkins 2.x version (currently 2.8, I need to install 2.7) on Ubuntu 14.04 with no success.

I added the repository as described in http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/

```
wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

then added following line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/
```

then the normal update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now if I want to install the latest 2.8 version, it works , but any other release like 2.7, 2.6... etc it fails

```
sudo apt-get  install jenkins=2.7

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.7' for 'jenkins' was not found
```

My problem is that I am automating our infrastructure using chef, whenever jenkins releases new version it break the chef run, so I have to stick to specific version, but with every release it cannot find any previuos one

Comment: Does it also fail with apt pinning? [Here's](https://github.com/lsinfo3/ls3-defaults/blob/bcd6afce2292495b05af9b9a302c9add3cb62df9/recipes/_chef-client.rb#L12-L15) how I use it for the `chef` package itself.

Comment: I am using apt_repository resource to add the repository to chef, but the problem is not chef specific, as I described you can reproduce it in the shell using apt-get

Comment: I added the following for pinning with no change
`apt_preference 'jenkins' do
  glob         '*'
  pin          'origin pkg.jenkins-ci.org/'
  pin_priority '700'
end`

Comment: Can you try to pin the version as done in the cookbook I referenced?

Comment: I tried, and it failed with the same error

Comment: Right.. ` apt-cache policy jenkins` really shows only the `2.8` version. What about downloading the `.deb` and installing it?

Comment: We are using chef, Unfortunately, jenkins do not provide us with checksum, without it chef will download the file every run, every 30min... this is not good :)

Comment: I'd say it servers doesn't support  `ETag` or `Last-Modified` headers (because of different mirrors have different `ETag`s?). If you manually specify the checksum, it wouldn't download it, because it compares it to the local file first (see [docs](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html#prevent-re-downloads)).